# Redirecting web service requests that no longer exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am working a legacy web service app which we has now changed, so that when existing customers make calls like http://ipaddress/SomeMethod1 this no longer exists and the call should be re-routed/redirected to http://ipaddress/Services/SomeMethod1 (note that there are lots of call like this (ie. someMethod2, someMethod3 etc)).

We cannot except the clients to change their applications and in addition some clients are just making simple Get/Post requests whilst others are using SOAP/WSDL generated end points.

I have seen some replies about using httphandlers, httpmodules, bindings etc but I am not sure what is the best way to address this problem with web services without breaking client code.

TIA

JD

Ps. We are using IIS/Asp.net/ASMX with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IIS Url rewrite for that. This guarantees that your client dont need to change the url.

More Informations:

[URL Rewrite for web service in sub folders in IIS](http://forums.iis.net/t/1182190.aspx)

[Regular Expression Info - Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks, when would I use URL Bindings? Also, does the rule have to exist in the machine config or the web.config of the app?

Comment: These changes should be in the web.config. You can use the IIS User interface to apply that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am currently doing it via the IIS user interface. Last question :), does it send back the final URL (re-written url) back to the client (via redirect http status code) or does it make the request from the server?

Comment: This is all internal in the iis. The client does not notice that.

Comment: Having a bit of an issue with the URL rewrite regular expression, how do I set the pattern for http://ipaddress/SomeMethod to http://ipaddress/Services/SomeMethod?

Comment: i updated my answer with helpful link for your regular expression problem. i am not a "Url-Rewrite-PRO" ;) but my answer should be right.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far. I think I may have an issue with having ipaddress in the expression. I'll do some more research.